# pybind11 and static members of classes set within function calls

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am a poor man's c++ user, so please be patient with any ignorance I display here.

I use pybind11 to create bindings between Kokkos views (the details of Kokkos are not terribly important, but a view is an abstract data container for portable (CPU/GPU) programming). This has worked great in the past. However, before using any Kokkos functionality, a void returning initializer function in Kokkos must be called. Easy enough, I wrap the `Kokkos::initialize()` function with pybind11, call it from the beginning of my python program, and all is well.

Recently, the Kokkos devs changed many of the class members created/set by the `Kokkos::initialize()` function to `inline static` members, and this has broken my use case with pybind11. A more detailed example:

`Kokkos::initialize()` creates a Kokkos defined cuda implementation class; call it `KokkosCudaImpl`, with an inline static member `m_maxThreadsPerSM` which gets set from a cuda library call. In the class definition:

```
class KokkosCudaImpl{
// stuff
inline static int m_maxThreadsPerSM = 0;
// more stuff
};
```

When `Kokkos::initialize()` is called, I see that the value pulled from the CUDA library for `m_maxThreadsPerSM` is `1024`, and is supposed to be used to set the `m_maxThreadsPerSM` member of the `KokkosCudaImpl`. However, when I go to use more features of Kokkos, like execute a compute kernel, the `m_maxThreadsPerSM` of the `KokkosCudaImpl` class is set back to `0`, and the kernel aborts with an error.

My question is really about how is the definition of the `inline static` members of the classes created when `Kokkos::initialize()` is called, and what happens between python ->pybind11->c++->pybind11->python exchange. Obviously this error is not present in pure c++ or it would never get off the ground, so the issue is with the pybind11 binding/lifetime/ownership.

Thanks for the help.